# Can someone help with this self invoking function stuff?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to debug this script all day and I got nothing any help would be greatly appreciated.

I keep getting an error that it's missing a curly brace or a square brace or a parenthetical. And also when I try to get the value of my options it says x is undefined but when I input 0 as my index I can retrieve opts.value, my question is why is x undefined and what's missing from this script

```
prices= (function(){    
          table=document.getElementsByTagName("table");
          selects=table[0].getElementsByTagName("select");
          for(var x=0;x<=10;x++){
            opts=new Array();
            opts=selects[x].getElementsByTagName("option")[selects[x].selectedIndex];
          }
          return{
            value: (function(){
                     val=new Array();
                     for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
                       val[i]=opts.value
                     }
                     return val;
                   })();,
            total: (function(){}
                     var num="$15.00"
                     var t;
                     for(var j=0;j<=3;j++){
                       t+=num.slice(1).valueOf();
                     }
                     return t
                    })();
          };    
})();

var hello="hello"
document.write("<p>hello</p>");//line just test whether or not function is working
document.write(opts.value);
```

Comment: I have to ask - why are you defining anonymous functions and then immediately calling them?

Comment: I've completely tidied up your code. A couple of pointers - Always terminate statements with `;` and secondly, formatting the code well helps to see where problems are. Where you are assigning a value to `total` for the returned object, there seems to be an extra closing curly brace at the end of that line. Thirdly, you might want to locally scope `opts` variable

Answer (score 1):

Well, if that script is in the `<head>` of your document, its trying to read DOM elements before they've been created, unless you're calling it via onload which you're not showing.

Your other option would be to put the `<script> ... </script>` at the bottom of your page right before the closing body. While I can't be 100% sure this is the problem because you haven't posted your HTML, this is a fair guess if you're getting undefined DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Closure Demo

**Sorry if I missed anything, I didn't try running it because I've kept the html scenario you were using.  Because it's using document.write, it will return the *default* selected option values from 11 selects in first table on the page.**

```
// I've changed your "demo" to show the use of a "closure"...
var prices = (function() { //maybe good to add var
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); //maybe good to add var
    var selects = table[0].getElementsByTagName("select"); //maybe good to add var

    var opts = new Array(); //pull it out of for loop and add var! FYI var opts = []; is equivalent.
    for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x++) { //your test requires at least eleven selects in the first table.
        opts[x] = selects[x].options[selects[x].selectedIndex]; // maybe wanted 11 selected options in a closure?
    }
    return { // remove both anonymous wrappers from your object literal (function(){ ... })();
        value: function() {
            var val = new Array();  //maybe very good to add var
            for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                val[i] = opts[i].value; //good to add ; read selected option.value x6 from opts array in closure!
            }
            return val;
        },
        total: function() { // deleted an extra }
            var num = "$15.00"; //add ;
            var t; // must initialize to 0 since you're using +=
            for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                t += num.slice(1).valueOf(); //  null +=15.00 x3
            }
            return t; // null, good to add ;
        }
    };
})();
// I'm guessing you've done too much work to have previously defined opts as a global, yes?
document.write(prices.value().join('\r\n<br />')); // selected values copied from the closure

/* //using document.write so all this need to run at the bottom of a page
var hello = "hello"; //good to add ;
document.write("<p>hello</p>"); //line just test whether or not function is working
document.write(opts.value); 
*/
```

See the comments for help fixing up price.total etc.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Don't forget to vote +1, I'm new & need the props.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `return t` is missing a semi-colon.

Also, in the anon-function following `total:`, you seem to have paired-brackets `{}` followed by more body, which finally ends with a mismatched closed-bracket just before `return t`.

If you fix those issues, I think you will be much further along towards having working code